Integrating MySQL Database via VPN in Next.js App on Vercel
I need to work on a project where I have to access and query a local database from a Next.js app deployed on Vercel. However, the local server hosting the database is configured with a VPN, and after some research on Google, I found out that Vercel does not support this configuration.
I've been considering a solution involving creating an API that mirrors the database to a remote server, but I'd prefer to avoid this option because the database is too large and complex.
Specifications:
- Microsoft server with MySQL database and VPN configured locally
- Next.js app deployed on Vercel
Thanks to everyone for any suggestions or insights.
I tried to search for plugins that would allow connecting to the database through VPN, and I found only one plugin that enables VPN connection in Node.js, but I wouldn't know how to implement the database with this solution.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-openvpn
